# Defining an extension method on IEnumerable<T> where T is specific kind of type?

Tags: .net, generics, collections

I want a method to only work on types which implement the /, +, -, * operators. Is there any "clean" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require an interface, such as IArithmetic.

Unfortunately, this doens't work currently.  This is a [highly requested feature](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94264), however.

There are [some workarounds](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94264#tabs), usually requiring working with a second generic parameter, but most wouldn't work with `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on Type Parameters.  So you can require T to implement an interface:

```
public static class Classy
{
    public static void Extension<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Ninjas) 
        where T : IMathStuff
    {

    }
}
```

This requires all T to implement IMathStuff.  Now, if you can't fit the operators into the interface IMathStuff, you can leave the interface blank as a [Marker Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and only apply it to classes that do implement the operators.

This kind of assumes you're working with all custom classes and not the built-in types.  It's a workaround for something that isn't exactly supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a clean way to do this.  You will need to implement IEnumberable<int>,  IEnumberable<float>... etc

Answer (score 0):

Not at compile-time.  You'd have to use reflection, I think.

A lot of those are value types such as int and long, "where T : struct" but there is no interface or base type that is common to them.